# how do i send a message to a specific client in Socket io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm using nodeJs ,express, mongodb & socket.io for real time notifications and messaging. I have successfully broadcasted notification to all clients but i'm having trouble sending a notification to a specific client.
I want to use clients object Id, is it possible??

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have and show what you tried so far?

Comment: this is the a snippet i tried 
`io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Connected '+socket.id)
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected')
  })

  
  socket.on('like', liker => {
    console.log('Liked by ' + liker.firstname)
    socket.broadcast.emit('liked', liker)
    io.to(`${socket.id}`).emit('liked', liker);
  })

  
})`

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your original answer and put your code snippet there.

Answer (score 5):

To send an event to a specific socket use `io.to` with the `socket.id` of the receiver.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
   io.to(socket.id).emit('private', 'Just for you bud');
});
```